# ASPNET Web API application return error in client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to develop a full stack web application using `ASP.NET Web Api`. Can I develop that using single `ASP.NET Web API` project, or else Do I want to develop a separate client application?

I have already developed a `REST service Web Api` application and runs well. But I cannot load the view files in the app. I tried to change the localhost ports in the same app. But I can give only one port.

Postman shows the data for the restful services. But client does not load. It gives a error like this.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /Views/Home/SupplierDetails.cshtml
>   Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0

Comment: I think that you're probably testing with the wrong path in Postman.  You can install swashbuckler to give you a helping hand to test your API.  Can you give us an outline or screenshot of your VS project, so we can know the names of the controllers, views, and API controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the front-end of your web application in ASP.NET, with the Web API operating alongside (in another controller) in the same web application.  In fact, that's a great way to "dog food" your API to make sure it is functional and useful for developers.

By creating the Web API, you make your API available for other clients and consumers; and your ASP.NET Web Application can be one of those clients.

Comment: I think what you have suggested in the last section is good as a solution. I will create another client application by using react or asp.net mvc client libraries. Thanks.

Comment: If your client application is NOT in the same application as your API you may want to look into the `CORS` restrictions on your API application.  Likely you will need to make some configuration to your API to authorize callers from a particular domain or make it publicly available. more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api